# Magento 2 data migration errors how to solve

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration, custom-field

We have installed migration tool in the Magento 2.3.1 EE (composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.3.1
)  would like migrate M1 commerce edition (1.14.3.1) to Magento 2.3.1 EE.

When we execute **data:migrate** getting below errors could you please suggest and advise how to to resolve these?

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.3.1/config.xml
```

1. Mismatch of `datatypes.Sourcedocument:sales_flat_order.Fields:party_number`
2. Destination fields `arenotmapped.Document:quote_address_item.Fields:carriergroup_idcarriergroupcarriergroup_shipping`
3. `Sourcefieldsarenotmapped.Document:tax_class.Fields:op_avatax_code`
4. [2019-08-05 10:06:35][ERROR]: Foreign key (FK_EAV_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID_EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) `constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 0 from`eav_entity_attribute`.`attribute_id`has no referenced records in`eav_attribute`
5. [2019-08-05 10:06:35][ERROR]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: `catalog_eav_attribute. Fields: is_displayed_in_autocomplete,is_used_in_spellcheck,facet_min_coverage_rate,facet_max_size,facet_sort_order,display_pattern,display_precision,sort_order_asc_missing,sort_order_desc_missing`
6. Incompatibility in data. Source document: `eav_attribute. Field: source_model. Error: Class privatesales/attribute_source_customergroup is not mapped in record attribute_id=206`
7. SQLSTATE[23000]: `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-Migration_Default' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME'`
8. [2019-08-06 08:00:47][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step:

   Inventory Step]: started
   100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
   [2019-08-06 08:00:47][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: inventory_source_item Source: 1576 Destination: 5923
   [2019-08-06 08:00:47][WARNING]: Volume Check failed

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: write full command you are trying also you must have ignore third party attribute from tables

Comment: @Nagaraju K, I hope you fixed mismatch of datatypes was fixed.

Comment: Yes @CodeForGood

Comment: @Nagaraju K, Did you do it like<ignore>
   <Datatype>yotpo_rich_snippets.reviews_count</Datatype>
</ignore>

Comment: Yes @CodeForGood we need to do it like that only.

Comment: @Nagaraju K, thanks for confirmation. I have completed data migration, but have been stuck with a peculiar issue. Could you please have a look at it see if you can share any insight?

Comment: please let me know what exact issue u r facing? can u describe